# Word/term meaning "conversion from one dialect to another"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, orthography, dialects

Is there a word in linguistics that means *conversion from one dialect to another dialect*?

In most sources in which I've looked¹, the word "translation" only means *conversion of one language to another language*. In some sources², the definition given is broad enough to where it **could** be used in such a way; however, in none of them is the word "dialect" or any such "-lect" derivative (e.g. *ideolect*, *sociolect*, *ethnolect*, etc.) mentioned in such a way.

So my questions are thus:

1. Is there a word meaning *conversion from one dialect to another dialect of the same language*?
2. Is there a word meaning *conversion from a dialect of one language to a dialect of another language*?
3. Can the word *translate* mean this type of conversion?

I also jumped to *translate* in the "related terms" tool on the right-hand side of the OED and looked at other *trans-* words that I didn't recognise, but I couldn't discover a word that meant this.

---

¹ These Wikipedia articles:

- [*Translation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation)
- [*Dialect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialect)
- [*Dialectometry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectometry)
- [*Dialectology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectology)

² These (probably more reliable) webpages (I put the relevant text is bold):

- [*Translate*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/204841), Oxford English Dictionary (OED):  {Subscription required}

> → `pt. I, sec. 1, def. a:`*To bear, convey, or remove from one person, place **or condition to another**; to transfer, transport*
>
> → `pt. II, sec. 2, def. a:` *also, **to express in other words**, to paraphrase. (The chief current sense.)*
>
> → `pt. II, sec. 2, def. b:` *to make a version from one language **or form of words into another**.*

- [*Translate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translate), Merriam-Webster

> → `pt. I, sec. 1, def. a:` *to bear, remove, or change from one place, state, **form, or appearance to another***
>
> → `pt. I, sec. 2, def. b:` *to transfer or turn from one set of symbols into another*
>
> [This is sometimes *transliteration*, true, but oftentimes the differences between dialects lie in their spelling (e.g. US vs UK spellings), so in these cases it can be considered both.]
>
> → `pt. I, sec. 2, def. c:` *to express in **different terms** and especially different words*
>
> [Since you can convert to different dialects just by changing a few letters (see above about pt. 1, sec. 2, def. b), I'd like to point out that I'm looking for a word that refers to **all** conversions of this type, not just at the level of words. Basically, we're talking just a word that means *conversion from dialect to dialect*, with no orthographic size specified.]

Comment: In software development, *localization* can involve converting phrases in the same language to those favored in different areas.

Comment: To my mind, *translation* is a good word for this. And what if the only ways humans spoke were using what we now call different "dialects" of English (or Chinese or...). Wouldn't we in that case call those different "languages", as they would be the only differences? Doesn't "dialect" come into the light only by way of there being very different degrees of similarity? And then there are surely [lumpers and splitters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumpers_and_splitters) when it comes to linguistics, just as there are when it comes to evolutionary biology, no? IOW, "language" is relative, no?

Comment: The distinction between dialect and language is arbitrary and fluid-- I'm reminded of the quote [a language is a dialect with an army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_language_is_a_dialect_with_an_army_and_navy).

Comment: @stevesliva: Interesting idea. However, that term doesn't mean as such in linguistics. In fact, it's not even a word in linguistics. The closest one could come to that word in language AFAIK is in the sphere of international business, in which it's the opposite of *globalisation*.

Comment: @Drew: Just because something is relative doesn't mean trends cannot be identified or concepts be formulated.

Comment: @Barmar: Like Drew, you're mostly splitting hairs here. Just because it is fluid and subjective doesn't mean it can't be measured. It oftentimes can be, even among linguists. Nevertheless, in many linguistic contexts, a dialect is "A particular form of a language that is peculiar to a specific region or social group."[¹](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dialect) So, if you must be so nitpicky, then go by this definition.

Comment: @SarahofGaia: Strawman - no one said otherwise.

Comment: @Drew: It's not a strawman. And yeah someone did say otherwise. You two are pointing out a minor detail that bears no relevance to the end goal of my point. Yes it's subjective, but I'm sure you know exactly what I mean, so why not cut to the chase and just answer the dang question? The ones below certain have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a specific word for this, but you could use ***[interpret](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interpret)*** here.

> To translate from one language into another.

(thefreedictionary.com)

*The words of that dialect were interpreted in this one.*

---

And yes, you could use *translate* for this purpose.

Comment: Hmm... I really don't like to use *translate* for that purpose, but yes I guess it could. That would still make sense. And yes, *interpreted* could work; although I suppose it would also depend a lot on context: if you're talking about interpreting something for someone from one dialect to another (e.g. explaining to a USAian that *fish and chips* in UK dialects means *fish and French fries* in USAian dialects), you could use it, but you'd have to be careful not to confuse it with other usages of that word.

Answer (score 3):

(1) 
I would use the word **render** (render dialect A into dialect B) to get around that problem. It has the advantage of carrying the meaning of "to translate" while having a broader sense of casting something/someone into a particular mode.

(2)
Wouldn't this be simply translation? As long as you're doing it between languages, it shouldn't matter whether you're moving between the standard languages or some smaller subsets.

(3)
Did you mean the type of conversion referred to in question 2?

Comment: (1) That *is* a good word. Thank you so much! (2) Hu... True. I didn't think of it like that. (3) I meant both. However, due to what you pointed out regarding #2, I guess now I'll say #1 is what it should refer to.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to match the idea of "code-switching" in linguistics.

> Linguistics . the alternating or mixed use of two or more languages, especially within the same discourse:

[-Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/code-switching)

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: Hi Kristine, glad to have you here.  We general eschew brief, contextless answers.  Could you please take a few minutes to color the answer a bit more, and maybe provide what you think is an ideal link, on this topic?

Answer (score -1):

"Code switching" is the term used for why some people quickly move from one dialect to another--but that's more about sociology than linguistics.